# Update attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

Given input like this

```xml
<div>
  <p>
    <x n="1"/>
    <x n=""/>
    <x n=""/>
    <x n=""/>
    <x n="190"/>
    <x n=""/>
    <x n=""/>
  </p>
</div>
```

I need to update the empty values of attribute `n` incrementally from the existing values to achieve this result:

```xml
<div>
  <p>
    <x n="1"/>
    <x n="2"/>
    <x n="3"/>
    <x n="4"/>
    <x n="190"/>
    <x n="191"/>
    <x n="192"/>
  </p>
</div>
```

I have tried this solution:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="x[@n = '']/@n">
        <xsl:attribute name="n" select="preceding::x[number(@n)]/@n + 1"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

-- which only produces:

```xml
<div>
   <p>
      <x n="1"/>
      <x n="2"/>
      <x n=""/>
      <x n=""/>
      <x n="190"/>
      <x n=""/>
      <x n=""/>
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: Saxon-HE 11.4. Same result with similar versions of Saxon-PE and Saxon-EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XSLT 3 and `xsl:iterate`:

```
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:iterate select="x">
        <xsl:param name="n" select="()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="n" select="if (@n and @n != '') then @n else $n + 1"/>
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:attribute name="n" select="$n"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:next-iteration>
          <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n"/>
        </xsl:next-iteration>
      </xsl:iterate>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

[Online example](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22p%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aiterate%20select%3D%22x%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22n%22%20select%3D%22%28%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22n%22%20select%3D%22if%20%28%40n%20and%20%40n%20%21%3D%20%27%27%29%20then%20%40n%20else%20%24n%20%2B%201%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aattribute%20name%3D%22n%22%20select%3D%22%24n%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-iteration%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Awith-param%20name%3D%22n%22%20select%3D%22%24n%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Anext-iteration%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aiterate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Acopy%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3Cdiv%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3Cp%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cx%20n%3D%221%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cx%20n%3D%22%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cx%20n%3D%22%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cx%20n%3D%22%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cx%20n%3D%22190%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cx%20n%3D%22%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cx%20n%3D%22%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fp%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E&input-type=XML).

Another option is using an accumulator:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:accumulator name="n" as="xs:integer?" initial-value="()">
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="p/x[@n and @n != '']" select="xs:integer(@n)"/>
    <xsl:accumulator-rule match="p/x[not(@n) or @n = '']" select="$value + 1"/>
  </xsl:accumulator>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy" use-accumulators="n"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="p/x/@n">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}" select="..!accumulator-before('n')"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way you could look at it:

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="x" group-starting-with="x[@n!='']">
            <xsl:variable name="n" select="@n" />
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:attribute name="n" select="$n + position() - 1"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```